# What's wrong with this line ? i'm trying to figure out since hours (php)

Tags: php, html

The following line of code is supposed to echo the current season and a data in a php echo:

```
<?php echo "<h5>"  $_SESSION['username'] '<span class="chat_date">'Dec 25"</span></h5>" ?>
```

Is the session call `true`?  And how can I fix this code?

Comment: What is "broken" / what needs to be "fixed"?  What does it do now, vs what do you want it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want echo a string you should use concatenation operator ('.')

```
<?php echo '<h5>' .$_SESSION['username']. '<span class="chat_date">Dec 25</span></h5>' ?>
```

or use double-quotes (") to passing data

```
$usename=$_SESSION['username'];
<?php echo '<h5>"$usename"<span class="chat_date">Dec 25</span></h5>' ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is no need to concatenate a string before echoing it in PHP.**

The parameters can be passed individually to `echo` as multiple arguments for a slight performance (speed) increase. In other words, you can use `,` instead of `.`.

**For example:**

```
<?php echo '<h5>' , $_SESSION['username'] , '<span class="chat_date">Dec 25</span</h5>'; ?>
```

---

I would recommend reading the [Official Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
    echo "<h5> $_SESSION[username] <span class=\"chat_date\">Dec 25</span></h5>"; 
?>
```

- Variables are evaluated inside double quoted strings.
- To echo double quotes inside double quotes, you add a backslash before the double quote so PHP knows it is not the end of the quoted segment.
- For arrays, do not quote the key inside a string.